# Question about using a charger/laptop from Iran in US (difference in voltage?)

Tags: conversion

I'm not really familiar with using electronics from other countries in the US and vice versa.  I know the outlets are different, but that's pretty much it.  I'm really sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question, but I don't know where else to ask it.

Here is the situation:

My sister works at a university here in the US, and has volunteered to help a visitor to the university from the country Iran get settled in (I think the visitor is actually a new Ph.D. student, so she will be living here for a few years at least).  The visitor has an HP laptop from Iran, with an adapter from Iran.

The visitor was under the impression that you can buy an HP charger from America, and it will somehow work with her computer, but I'm pretty sure (though not certain) that that's not a good idea and could damage the laptop.

On the other hand, we've been looking in to finding an American outlet plug adapter/converter thing that will allow her to plug her charger from Iran into a US outlet.  The problem is, I've found conflicting information online about which type of outlets are in Iran.  But I found a great device on Amazon which claims to be a "universal to American outlet plug adapter".  And it's pretty cheap at $5.30.

Will this device work?  Do I need anything else?  I'm worried that once the visitor plugs the charger from Iran into this device, then this device into the outlet, that it will somehow still damage the laptop.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the ratings on the present charger - the chargers for most notebook or netbook computers are "universal" - they will accept 100 - 240 volts (or so) and 50/60 Hz input power, so all you need is a simple adaptor to allow the Iranian plug to connect to a US outlet.  Any US computer dealer handling HP products should be able to supply a suitable cord (no new charger required).

Comment: @PeterBennett Thanks for your comment!  I tried linking the product on amazon into the question, but it looks like the link didn't show up (maybe the system thought it was spam).  The product on amazon is titled BoxWave Universal to American Outlet Plug Adapter.  If you have a minute, could you search that and let me know if it looks suitable to what you were saying?  Thank you either way!

Comment: @user46944 I seriously doubt that anyone has shipped a laptop with a _non_ universal power supply for at least fifteen years. Certainly HP has not. So, as far as voltage and frequency are concerned, it'll be fine. And btw, you want to get the "with ground pin" version of the adapter. The  one illustrated in Spehro's answer is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have problems. Iran http://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/iran/ runs on 230 VAC / 50 Hz. The US is 115 VAC / 60 Hz. Simply getting a plug adapter will probably not work, although it might. The question is, what voltage range does an HP charger accept? If it's 90 - 240 VAC input, you'll be fine with an adapter. If not, you'll need to buy a charger that is used in the US. You'll need to do some research at the HP website to determine what you need. Because you're switching from a high voltage system to a lower voltage, if the charger is not compatible you probably won't hurt anything, but you won't charge the battery or run the laptop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think my sister said the charger accepts 110v to 220v.  So if we get a US-version HP charger, it should have no problems working with the HP laptop from Iran?

Comment: If your sister is correct, you don't need a new charger, just a plug adapter.

Comment: I tried linking the product from Amazon that I thought was the plug adapter, but the link isn't there (maybe the system thought it was spam).  If you have a minute, can you search on Amazon for exactly "BoxWave Universal to American Outlet Plug Adapter" and let me know if the first item in the search result is what you mean by "plug adapter"?  Thank you either way!

Comment: @user46944 - I've no experience with Iranian power cords, but the adapter looks as if it ought to work. Certainly it's the sort of thing I meant.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'charger' is labeled to accept North American power as well as Iranian power (which is the same as that used in Europe and much of the rest of the world) then all that is required is a plug adapter.

Plug adapters are passive and cannot damage anything. They're also cheap. She should probably buy it locally before leaving, maybe a few dollars. The ones easily available in U.S. travel stores go the other way (Euro plug to U.S. Socket).

Typically the computer charger will say something like 100-240V and 50-60Hz, which includes both Iranian power standards and U.S. 120VAC 60Hz. Maybe send her a photo of the plug types used in North America.

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095FMXA6) is a decent one that will handle 'Schuko' grounded plugs and adapt them to have a grounded U.S. plug: (I'm sure there are others).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most computer power supplies, laptop or otherwise are switch mode. This means that they'll accept a range of voltages, and output what's needed. You almost certainly will not need a new power supply. You'll either want a new powercord from wall to powerbrick or a travel adaptor, but the power supply itself should be fine.